# How do I get device serial number under Android 9 and newer using Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo, serial-number

I know that for earlier Android versions this is done using `TJBuild.JavaClass.SERIAL`. Starting with Android 9 `SERIAL` method is expected to return `"UNKNOWN"` string and so I need to use the new `getSerial` method, but it doesn't (presumably, yet) exist in `TJBuild` class.

I've looked around for some code samples but haven't found any and I'm not good at converting Java code into Delphi.

I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Code for using `SERIAL` method:

```
uses Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.Os;
```

```
function GetSerial: string;
begin
  Result := JStringToString (TJBuild.JavaClass.SERIAL);
end;
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build#getSerial() is new since API 26 (Android 8, Oreo). Does your project target API 26 (or newer) or an older API level?

Comment: @mjn42 The app is targeting Android API 24. I read in a blog about changes in Android 8 and `SERIAL` method that "To avoid breaking legacy app functionality, apps targeting prior versions of Android will continue see the device's serial number, as before." I suppose this means that I should use `SERIAL` method and my app should be future-proof is this regard, if I don't upgrade the target API. Thank you!

Comment: What are you using the serial number for? If it's for a unique id, you might be able to use something else

Comment: @DaveNottage I need a unique id which remains unchanged on the device. I know I can use Android ID, but it changes when the device is reset to factory settings and it's different for different users of the device. So the solution is to use IMEI and/or device serial number, depending on what's available.

Comment: Good luck with finding something that reliably returns the sane unique id no matter what. You could use a GUID that is generated when the app is first run. It is guaranteed to not be the same for any other device. If the user uninstalls the app, then reinstalls, what do they expect?

Comment: Yes if you target a level < 26 then SERIAL is your only option, an must work even when run on devices with newer API levels

Comment: You could use the IMEI number of the device.

Comment: @mjn42 The app will be targeting Android API 26 now, because I want the app to meet Google Play's target API level requirement.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Yes, thank you. I use both IMEI and serial, because to my knowledge IMEI might be empty on devices without telephony and serial might be empty on devices with telephony.